# ¿Existe algo como typeof en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como el titulo dice, hay forma de obtener el tipo de dato interno de una variable en Python 3?

En C# puedo compararlo de la siguiente forma:

```
var str = "Strings";

if (str.GetType() == typeof(string))
    Debug.WriteLine("str es un string.");
```

Pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo en python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sí, en lugar de `typeof` es `type`:

```
>>> type("hola mundo")
<type 'str'>
>>> type(6)
<type 'int'>
>>>
```

**Edito:** En python 3 devuelve `class` en lugar de `type` pero supongo que eso no afecta en este caso:

```
>>> type("hola mundo")
<class 'str'>
>>> type(6)
<class 'int'>
>>> type([1,2])
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: Entendido, no es necesario el `equality` op para ello, no? Puedo compararlos usando `is`?

Comment: No sé mucho de python, solo un poco de lo más básico pero sí, comparar el tipo entre dos valores es tan fácil como:  `type([1,2]) is type("hola")`

Comment: Ahora dudo si te he entendido, igual no quieres comparar entre dos variables si no con un tipo concreto, algo así: `type(cadena) is str` si cadena es un string te devuelve `true`

Comment: Exacto, esa parte queria saber en lo que pregunté en el comment, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 6):

Como en C#, en python se habla de tipos y clases indistintamente. La diferencia está en python hay herencia múltiple y preguntar por el tipo de un objeto queda algo ambiguo.

La foma correcta de comprobar el tipo de un objeto es usando `isinstance` (equivalente al `is` de C#):

```
>>> isinstance(s, str)
true
```

Comment: Me gusta mucho esta.

Comment: Tengo un caso parecido, pero no puedo comparar el tipo porque es dinámico, entonces ¿cómo puedo saber el tipo? He probado con type(instancia) y me devuelve una cadena que no puedo manipular "<class 'catalogo.models.Articulo'>". Solo necesito la clase "Articulo". ¿Cómo lo hago sin usar "split" ni regex?

Comment: Si es dinámico, ¿de qué sirve saber cómo se llama cuando clases distintas pueden tener el mismo nombre? `type(instancia)` te da una referencia a la clase, que no un nombre. Si tienes una pregunta concreta, mejor que la formules nueva.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción en Python, podría ser:

```
>>> a = [] # Lista
>>> str(type(a)) == '<class \'list\'>'
    True
>>> b = () # Tupla
>>> str(type(b)) == '<class \'list\'>'
    False
>>> a = tuple(a)
>>> str(type(a)) == '<class \'tuple\'>'
    True
>>> str(type(b)) == '<class \'tuple\'>'
    True
```

Obvio que debemos saber los tipos de datos correspondientes.

Aunque...

```
isinstance(, )
```

... está super!

Answer (score -1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente para obtener el tipo de dato de cada objeto o variable:

```
mylista = [123,123.0,"'123'",True]
for tipo in mylista:
     print(f'<{tipo}> es un tipo de dato {type(tipo).__name__}')
print(f'<mylista> es un tipo de datos {type(mylista).__name__}')

Salida:
    
<123>   es un tipo de dato int

<123.0> es un tipo de dato float

<'123'> es un tipo de dato str

<True>  es un tipo de dato bool

<mylista> es un tipo de datos list
```